# c#.net to vb.net: List(of ...) .find

Tags: c#, vb.net

Can someone please translate the following C#.NET to VB.NET for me, as I'm really confused, and google isn't much help.  Normally I would just do a for each loop.

```
Public void removeEval(string id)
{
    evals.Remove(evals.Find(e => e.Id.Equals(id)));
}
```

I got the code from http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/Endpoint-Screencasts-Creating-Your-First-WCF-Service/ and I'm trying to make sense of it in VB.NET.

Comment: BTW, that should be `=>`, not `>=`.

Comment: Use http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Answer (score 3):

That's a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx):

```
evals.Remove(evals.Find(Function(e) e.Id.Equals(id)))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting an error of 'Equal' is not a member of string.

Comment: It's ok, it should be Equals with an s not Equal. So thank you.

Answer (score 0):

google gave me this http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

which translates this function to:

```
Public Sub removeEval(id As String)
    evals.Remove(evals.Find(Function(e) e.Id.Equals(id)))
End Sub
```

after I corrected this: `evals.Find(e => e.Id.Equals(id)));`

Answer (score 0):

```
 Public Sub RemoveEvals(ByVal id As String)
       evals.Remove(evals.Find(Function(e) e.Id.Equals(id)))
 End Sub
```